# Persisted API tokens in Spring Boot 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to generate, persist and validate API tokens for users. No need of an extensive OAuth2 implementation with client id, secret etc. Send username, password to the API and retrieve a token which can be used for further requests. These tokens should be persisted in database and i should be able to manually invalidate the tokens from the backend. This is very similar to [Laravel sanctum API tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication).

How do I do this in Spring Security? I don't prefer JWT token or any persisted flavours of the same.

Comment: How about Spring Session for API protection? check my sample for [backend APIs](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-reactive-sample) and [microservice](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-microservice-sample).

Comment: you may use Spring Session https://www.baeldung.com/spring-session-jdbc

Comment: Please, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64607385/how-to-secure-communication-between-2-spring-boot-microservices-using-oauth2/64648035#64648035) and the different answers provided. In one of them I expose a solution that, except for the persistence of tokens, which on the other hand should be easily included, I think fits very well your needs.